# Android Chrome always has 229 as key code for input

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

So I have a input where I am limiting it to numbers and a few extra characters by checking the `event.which`.  The issue I am running into is that on android, event.which always returns 229.  I have tried to turn off auto correct and auto complete however the issue still happens.  Using type="number" also does not work as it is not just numbers but other characters too.

Is there any way around this issue?

Comment: Judging by [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639#), 229 is used as an indication that there is text being entered but it's not ready to be committed yet. However, it seems to suggest that it should *also* fire `keydown/up` events with the correct key codes after 229, which I don't see happening.